# MYSQL how SUM by birthdate every 5 years

Tags: mysql

How I can do a query in MYSQL to

SELECT SUM of People_id from table and group by birthdate every 5 years??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Run the query above. Wait 5 years. Run the query again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/644e2d/2

```
SELECT (YEAR(birthdate) - MOD(YEAR(birthdate),5)) as `year`,COUNT(id)
FROM users
GROUP BY `year`
```